# android S3 wifi problems due to update

Tags: wi-fi

After the update, my phone tries to connect to wifi networks (which my tablet connects to just fine) and then says "internet not available". How do i solve this?

Comment: There is no passphrase; it is an open network. In fact, all of them have been

Comment: What update is this?

Answer (score 0):

Goto settings>WiFi> select SSID, you'll have options for forget and connect. Select forget. Then select SSID. Enter passphrase. Then select connect